# Localstack : Creating stack from cloudformation file which refer to some existing reources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, localstack

I am trying to deploy a stack using localstack.

My cloudformation file refer to few existing resources which are already created on the `dev` environment.

While deploying my cloudformation I am getting below errors:

```
2022-10-03T10:17:26.431 DEBUG --- [  Thread-256] l.u.c.template_deployer    : Error applying changes for CloudFormation stack "ashford1": An error occurred (InternalError) when calling the AttachRolePolicy operation (reached max retries: 4): exception while calling iam.AttachRolePolicy: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/aws/chain.py", line 90, in handle
handler(self, self.context, response)
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/aws/handlers/service.py", line 122, in __call__
handler(chain, context, response)
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/aws/handlers/service.py", line 92, in __call__
skeleton_response = self.skeleton.invoke(context)
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/aws/skeleton.py", line 153, in invoke
return self.dispatch_request(context, instance)
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/aws/skeleton.py", line 165, in dispatch_request
result = handler(context, instance) or {}
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/aws/forwarder.py", line 60, in _call
return fallthrough_handler(context, req)
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/moto.py", line 83, in _proxy_moto
return call_moto(context)
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/moto.py", line 46, in call_moto
return dispatch_to_backend(context, dispatch_to_moto, include_response_metadata)
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/aws/forwarder.py", line 113, in dispatch_to_backend
http_response = http_request_dispatcher(context)
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/moto.py", line 111, in dispatch_to_moto
status, headers, content = dispatch(request, request.url, request.headers)
File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/moto/core/responses.py", line 217, in dispatch
return cls()._dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/moto/core/responses.py", line 356, in _dispatch
return self.call_action()
File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/moto/core/responses.py", line 443, in call_action
response = method()
File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/moto/iam/responses.py", line 17, in attach_role_policy
self.backend.attach_role_policy(policy_arn, role_name)
File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/moto/iam/models.py", line 1689, in attach_role_policy
policy = arns[policy_arn]
KeyError: 'arn:aws:iam::XXXXX:policy/BasePolicy-Default-XXX'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/cloudformation/template_deployer.py", line 1569, in _run
self.do_apply_changes_in_loop(changes, stack)
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/cloudformation/template_deployer.py", line 1646, in do_apply_changes_in_loop
self.apply_change(change, stack=stack)
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/cloudformation/template_deployer.py", line 1723, in apply_change
result = deploy_resource(self, resource_id)
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/cloudformation/template_deployer.py", line 853, in deploy_resource
result = execute_resource_action(resource_id, stack, ACTION_CREATE)
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/cloudformation/template_deployer.py", line 891, in execute_resource_action
result = func["function"](resource_id, resources, resource_type, func, stack_name)
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/cloudformation/models/iam.py", line 294, in _post_create
iam.attach_role_policy(RoleName=role_name, PolicyArn=arn)
File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 514, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 938, in _make_api_call
raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InternalError) when calling the AttachRolePolicy operation (reached max retries: 4): exception while calling iam.AttachRolePolicy: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/aws/chain.py", line 90, in handle
handler(self, self.context, response)
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/aws/handlers/service.py", line 122, in __call__
handler(chain, context, response)
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/aws/handlers/service.py", line 92, in __call__
skeleton_response = self.skeleton.invoke(context)
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/aws/skeleton.py", line 153, in invoke
return self.dispatch_request(context, instance)
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/aws/skeleton.py", line 165, in dispatch_request
result = handler(context, instance) or {}
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/aws/forwarder.py", line 60, in _call
return fallthrough_handler(context, req)
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/moto.py", line 83, in _proxy_moto
return call_moto(context)
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/moto.py", line 46, in call_moto
return dispatch_to_backend(context, dispatch_to_moto, include_response_metadata)
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/aws/forwarder.py", line 113, in dispatch_to_backend
http_response = http_request_dispatcher(context)
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/moto.py", line 111, in dispatch_to_moto
status, headers, content = dispatch(request, request.url, request.headers)
File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/moto/core/responses.py", line 217, in dispatch
return cls()._dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/moto/core/responses.py", line 356, in _dispatch
return self.call_action()
File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/moto/core/responses.py", line 443, in call_action
response = method()
File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/moto/iam/responses.py", line 17, in attach_role_policy
self.backend.attach_role_policy(policy_arn, role_name)
File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/moto/iam/models.py", line 1689, in attach_role_policy
policy = arns[policy_arn]
KeyError: 'arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:policy/Policy-Default-XXXX'
```

My questions:

1. Should I create the `existing resources` manually before deploying the stack?
2. Can I create the stack with multiple resource files places in `cloudformation.d` folder? As of now, I need to create a single cloudformation.yml file and use that to deploy stack.

Thanks for your time and help.